# Remove multiple elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

In my current code I have like

```
$("#foo").remove();
$("#bar").remove();
```

Are there any way to remove multiple elements by using `remove()` once?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not limited to `.remove()`, but just separate the selectors by a comma:

```
$("#foo, #bar").remove();
```

[Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”) | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

> **Description:** Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.
>
> `jQuery( "selector1, selector2, selectorN" )`
>
> selector1: Any valid selector.
>
> selector2: Another valid selector.
>
> selectorN: As many more valid selectors as you like.

Answer (score 3):

You need comma separated [multiple selector](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+multiple+selector) to target multiple elements.Try this:

```
 $("#foo,#bar").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

To select multiple elements in jQuery, the syntax is

```
$('#foo, #bar').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove multiple empty div tags.

```
 $(".className1.className2").each(function() {
        var current_element = $(this);      

        if(current_element.text().trim()==""){
            current_element.remove();
        }       
  });
```