# jQuery remove two element on var

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var li = $('div.notification').parents("li");
var hr = li.next("hr");

li.remove();
hr.remove();
```

How to delete two elements in one time ? Like (li && hr).remove();

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove multiple elements in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103739/remove-multiple-elements-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `add`:

```
li.add(hr).remove()
```

Comment: Another option is `$('div.notification').closest('li').next('hr').addBack().remove()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("li:has(div.notification), li:has(div.notification) + hr").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="notification">notification</div>
  </li>
  <hr>
    <li>
    <div class="notification">notification</div>
  </li>
  <hr>
    <li>
    <div class="not-notification">not notification</div>
  </li>
  <hr>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. You can't use the `parents` method that way. It just selects a _parent_ element.

Comment: The `closest`  also won't select the `hr` element because of the reason mentioned in my previous comment. `$('div.notification').closest('li').next('hr').addBack().remove()` should work.